# Twisty puzzle composed of hexagonal prisms, with As and diamonds

Tags: puzzle-identification, cards, twisty-puzzles

[image]
(click to enlarge)

My friend let me have a go of his cube and neither of us know what its called or where to buy one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was first released in June 2004 by Mefferts under the name Jackpot, and later it was renamed Platypus, and after that the New Generation Puzzle. It probably was sold under other names as well.

See for example [this site](https://www.cs.brandeis.edu/%7Estorer/JimPuzzles/ZPAGES/zzzPlatypus.html) for some info. There were several versions, including the Supreme edition which lights up a face when it is solved.

Unfortunately it has not been in production for some time, so there is nowhere that you can buy one new.